# Alternative of many AND condition

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am working on hive query where I have conditions. ex

```
select id, name from students
where id not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Hive does not support not in

```
select id, name from students
where (id <> 1 OR id <> 2 OR id <> 3 OR id <> 4 OR id <> 5 
OR id <> 6 OR id <> 7 OR id <> 8 OR id <> 9 OR id <> 10);
```

Am I doing right approach, if not. please suggest me the alternative.

Comment: `NOT IN`translates to `AND`: `where (id <> 1 AND id <> 2 AND ..`

Comment: No, you must use `AND` instead of `OR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Logical Operators section of https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

NOT IN queries are now supported.

> A NOT IN (val1, val2, ...) | Boolean | TRUE if A is not equal to any of the values. As of Hive 0.13 subqueries are supported in NOT IN statements.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF), Hive *does* support `NOT IN`:

> A NOT IN (val1, val2, ...) boolean TRUE if A is not equal to any of
>   the values. As of Hive 0.13 subqueries are supported in NOT IN
>   statements.

You may be confusing `NOT IN` with subqueries, but that is not the structure of your query.

Plus, you could always do:

```
WHERE NOT (id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) )
```

And, the issue with your query is that the `or`s should be `and`s.